# How to compile a java web application by javac?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javac, web.xml

I have a traditional Java web project, it's structure displayed as below

```
|-lib
|-src
   |-main
      |-java
      |-resources
|-wbeapps
   |-WEB-INF
      |-web.xml
```

I compile and run this application by IDEA's tomcat configuration before, all the issues about compile, run and deploy is done by IDEA.

Now, I must modify a java file of `src\main\java\xxx`, and this modification is absolutely correct, then not using IDEA or Eclipse to achieve the compilation and deploy to Tomcat.

How can I do that without IDEA or Eclipse, just use javac or other tools? Please give me some advices, thanks.

Comment: Use a build tool that understands about building WAR files; e.g. Maven, Gradle, etc

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to have a war (web application archive) file if you want to deploy to Tomcat. To generate a war file, first, compile all of your files using javac, and then run the jar command:

```
jar -cvf project.war *
```

This command should be run from the root project directory (not inside WEB-INF or any other folders).

The -c option specifies that you want to create a file, the -v option will generate verbose output, and the -f option allows you to specify the archive name.